# Estructura dentro de una estructura

Tags: c, struct

Estoy intentando crear una estructura dentro de otra estructura para tener más organizado mi código, pero no sé si lo estoy haciendo correctamente.
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
typedef struct
{
    int dato1;
    int dato2;
    typedef struct
    {
        int dato3;
    } estructura_interna_t estructura_interna;
} estructura_externa_t
```

Para acceder a las variables... ¿es correcto hacerlo así?:

```
// Declaración
struct estructura_externa_t datos;

//Acceso a las variables
datos.dato1 = 1;
datos.dato2 = 5;
datos.estructura_interna.dato3 = 10;
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que declarar primero el `struct` de mas interno a mas externo.

De este modo te permitirá hacerlo.

Te paso un ejemplo.

```
struct enterprise_detail
{
    int enterprise_id;
    char enterprise_name[50];
};
 
struct worker_detail 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float salary;
    // structure within structure
    struct enterprise_detail e_data;
}w_data;

...

//en el main
struct worker_detail w_data = {1, "Pepe", 25000.5, 71145, "Enterprise INC"};
```

---

Para editar valores o para verlos seria asi:

```
    printf(" Id is: %d \n", w_data.id);
    printf(" Name is: %s \n", w_data.name);
    printf(" Percentage is: %f \n\n", w_data.percentage);
 
    printf(" Enterprise Id is: %d \n", w_data.e_data.enterprise_id);
    printf(" Enterprise Name is: %s \n", w_data.e_data.enterprise_name);
```

Comment: Siguiendo tu ejemplo... Para modificar los valores de la estructura cómo se haría? `w_data.id = 12;  w_data.name="manolito"; w_data.e_data.enterpriese_id=100;` Esta asignación sería válida?

Comment: Lo que comentas es solamente una forma de hacerlo. La propuesta que figura en la pregunta es tan válida como la tuya

Comment: @Londo modifico para que veas como, lo que dices es correcto.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Srsole

Answer (score 1):

> Para acceder a las variables... ¿es correcto hacerlo así?:

Si no fuese una forma correcta de hacerlo el programa no compilaría.

El código que presentas es correcto

Comment: No dice que esta mal o no, el OP dice: "para tener mas organizado"

Comment: La organización depende de lo que tengas que hacer ... no por tener cada estructura separada del resto el código final va a estar necesariamente mejor organizado

Comment: @Srsole es lo que tienen las preguntas basadas en opiniones. No hay un algoritmo que calcule el nivel de organización de un código que nos permita comprar qué forma es _más correcta_. Este es un parámetro completamente subjetivo y salvo casos muy claros, cualquiera de las dos soluciones suele ser buena

Comment: Pero para eso existen los standares no?

Comment: Estpy convencido que debe existir uno sobre esto

Comment: @Srsole estándar de que? Al estandar de C te refieres?

Comment: yo lo veo como DDL de una base de datos, no puedes declarar una que tenga nested tables si no has declarado la anterior antes.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126441/discussion-between-srsole-and-eferion).

Comment: Existen estándares de dos niveles, uno se aplica a sectores completos, como MISRA-C, y otros a proyectos concretos, como el JSF AV C++ Coding Standard. Luego existe todo un conjunto de patrones de diseño que ayudan a establecer buenas y malas prácticas de programación y de organización.

Comment: @V.Lorz un patrón de diseño no entra en cómo se implementan las cosas. Un patrón de diseño se centra en una arquitectura que te permite solucionar un problema, pero la implementación correrá de tu cuenta. No vas a encontrar un patrón de diseño que te diga si debes crear estructuras anidadas o no

Comment: Por otro lado, lo que comentas de esos estándares, son reglas de codificación. Resulta curioso que muchas de estos _estándares_ no se metan en cómo se deben organizar las estructuras. Y por cierto, cada empresa puede tener su propias reglas de codificación, siendo este decálogo más o menos estricto y extenso según sus necesidades.

Comment: Es decir, si alguien hace una pregunta y se refiere a unas reglas de códificación determinadas, entonces SÍ se puede determinar si el código que ha puesto cumple esas reglas o no, pero si no se indica ninguna entonces la pregunta es subjetiva y, por tanto, basada en opiniones

Comment: Mi comentario era sólo eso, un comentario, y la información que aporta es sólo eso, información que puede ser de interés para los colegas que leen las soluciones que se aportan.

Comment: @V.Lorz no lo discuto, pero la información tiene un contexto, si tu la pones sin el contexto entonces parece que estás criticando a otra persona exponiendo esos argumentos como si fuesen una verdad absoluta, y esa no es la realidad. De ahí que yo haya expuesto mis diferencias respecto a esas afirmaciones que has hecho